# Looking for options to use Mapfish with PHP

Tags: php, mapfish

I recently installed MapFish on my test server and started to play around with. As I'm not that good in python/pylon I'd prefer to work with that framework with PHP.

I read that it is possible with sfMapfish which is a connector to the symphony-framework for PHP. Symphony is quite a strong framework, so I'm open to use it.

My questions are:

1. Has anyone used sfMapFish already and can show me a good tutorial to see how to start?
2. Is there another PHP Framework for MapFish (as sfMapfish hasn't been updated for over a year)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no explicit documentation but you could explore the source code into the [offcial plugin repository](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/plugins/sfMapFishPlugin/branches/1.4) to know how it works. Note that, the plugin is for sf1.3 / 1.4 versions but it does not exist for sf 2.

Mapfish uses REST, so you will find some valid documentation also on that page : http://trac.mapfish.org/trac/mapfish/wiki/MapFishProtocol

(From what I know, there is no other PHP framework supporting mapfish)

In your position, since there is no documentation on Symfony plugin and Mapfish is written in Python and much more documented for that language I would start the project using it.